# 'MatlabWorkSpace' object is not callable

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, matlab-deployment

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
for line in matcode:
    eng.workspace(line, nargout=0)

res = eng.workspace['x']
eng.quit()
```

and matcode.txt object string is

```
'x = [1 1;1 2;1 3;1 4];'
```

Couldn't figure out why is this happening :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lreg.py", line 14, in <module>
  main()
File "lreg.py", line 10, in main
  data = matlab_engine.start_engine(code_object)
File "/Users/hiteshkr/PycharmProjects/MLCO/matlab_engine.py", line 7,  in start_engine
  eng.workspace(line, nargout=0)
TypeError: 'MatlabWorkSpace' object is not callable
```

Comment: `eng.workspace` is a python Dictionary.  The syntax you are using isn't valid.  Are you sure that you aren't wanting to use `eng.eval(...)`?

Comment: Oh! that is it ! That's so silly of me. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @PhilGoddard How efficient is it to implement complex algorithms written in  matlab to execute in python this way from Machine learning point of view ?